# can i increase my adapter current?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, current, dc, dc-motor

i have an adapter that its output is:
DC 4.9 volt and 450 m ampere
i want use this adapter for running three 6 volt dc motors but the adapter output current is low, so i want amplify that.
can i do this with transistor? 
and which transistor should i use?
the adapter would be damaged if the motors draw this current??

Comment: Noooooooooooooooo you can't.

Comment: can you explain more please???

Comment: The maximum energy delivered by your adapter : 4.9V * 450mA = 2.205W cannot be 'magically' augmented without additional power sources (a battery, solar panels, a nuclear power plant..). Else, you would have invented a perpetual movement device.

Comment: @ramon - "can you explain more please???" Sorry, but no. You clearly have no faint idea how transistors work, and I can't explain it in 500 characters. Go do some studying.

Comment: When I was a kid I thought: hmm, a transistor amplifies current. So empty battery + transistor = full battery :-)
Obviously it doesn't work like that. So I studied electronics and now I understand why :-) But you don't have to go that far, reading some books about hobby-electronics will get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: That power supply plus a transistor can act as a switch to let a bigger current pass through **(that came from another power supply)**. So you're better off using that bigger supply in the first place. You cannot magically increase a power supply's current and/or voltage, unless you open it up and mess with the internals, which would most likely kill you or burn your house down.